# Laravel - How to save API rest endpoint data into my database

Tags: laravel, api

I am using Laravel 5.8 in my server. I have this external endpoint:

> https://api.abclm.net/customerss/allcustomers

It is a GET Request and in JSON the format as shown below.

```js
[
  {
    "ClientID": "C001",
    "ClientName": "ABU PLC",
    "Address": "ADDRESS LINE 1",
    "City": "Lagos"
  },
    "ClientID": "C002",
    "ClientName": "ADE PLC",
    "Address": "ADDRESS LINE 1",
    "City": "Lagos"
  },
    "ClientID": "C003",
    "ClientName": "JACOB PLC",
    "Address": "ADDRESS LINE 1",
    "City": "Lagos"
  }
]
```

Then, in my server I have this table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `customers` (
`id` int NOT NULL,
`client_id` varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
`client_name` varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`city` varchar(255) NOT NULL

) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The model class is Customer.

1. client_id and client_name are unique and should be reference points.
2. I want to save all the data in the endpoint at the same time in my Customer model class.
3. It should update where client_id and client_name already exists but insert where not
4. ClientID into client_id, ClientName into client_name, Address into address

I have something like this, but don't know how to continue:

```
     public function apiclient(Request $request)
{
        $array_content=[];

     $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.abclm.net/customerss/allcustomers");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //Important
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
          curl_close ($ch);
    $i=0;
    foreach(...)
    {
    $newobj = new Clients();

    ....
    array_push($array_content,$newobj);

    $i++;
    }
    return $array_content;
}
```

I have something like this but don't know how to go about it. Kindly assist.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using manual curl i thing this wrapper to easier the process
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

```php
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET','https://api.abclm.net/customerss/allcustomers');
return $res->getBody();
```

hope it help

Answer (score 0):

After you get response from your api request, you need to cast it to json first. To do that just use `json_decode` function from php.

```
$json_results = json_decode($result, true); // cast json to assoc array which you can easily use in for loop later
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the result is an array of clients you need to loop through it.

Since it should update where the existing records use `updateOrCreate()` function. The first parameter of this function is the array of key values which need to be checked for existence. And the second parameter is the array of key values which needs to be updated.

```php
// If the $result is an json string, use this to convert it to an array.
$clients = json_decode($result, true);

foreach($clients as $client) {
    Client::updateOrCreate([
        'client_id' => $client->ClientID,
        'client_name' => $client->ClientName,
    ],[
        'address' => $client->Address,
        'city' -> $client->City,
    ]);
}
```